# Wrong boolean result in the main program (python)

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I'm trying to write this simple code in Python: if the second element of a line of a csv file contains one of the family specified in the "malware_list" list, the main program should print "true". However, the result, is that the program prints always "FALSE".

Each line in the file is in the form: 
"NAME,FAMILY"

This is the code:

```
malware_list = ["FakeInstaller","DroidKungFu", "Plankton",
            "Opfake", "GingerMaster", "BaseBridge",
            "Iconosys", "Kmin", "FakeDoc", "Geinimi",
            "Adrd", "DroidDream", "LinuxLotoor", "GoldDream"
            "MobileTx", "FakeRun", "SendPay", "Gappusin",
            "Imlog", "SMSreg"]

def is_malware (line):
    line_splitted = line.split(",")
    family = line_splitted[1]
    if family in malware_list:
        return True
    return False

def main():
    with open("datset_small.csv", "r") as f:
        for i in range(1,100):
            line = f.readline()
            print(is_malware(line))

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: Python has a `csv` module that knows how to correctly parse CSV files (which is more complicated than simply splitting a line on each and every comma it sees).

Comment: What is the content of the csv-file?

Comment: @Daniel it's formed by lines in this form:
090b5be26bcc4df6186124c2b47831eb96761fcf61282d63e13fa235a20c7539,Plankton

bedf51a5732d94c173bcd8ed918333954f5a78307c2a2f064b97b43278330f54,DroidKungFu

149bde78b32be3c4c25379dd6c3310ce08eaf58804067a9870cfe7b4f51e62fe,Plankton

Comment: @Pierfrancesco: edit your question

Comment: Do you KNOW that your inputs will always match capitalization forms you're using in you malware_list?

Answer (score 4):

```
line = f.readline()
```

`readline` doesn't strip the trailing newline off of the result, so most likely `line` here looks something like `"STEVE,FakeDoc\n"`. Then `family` becomes `"FakeDoc\n"`, which is not a member of `malware_list`, so your function returns False.

Try stripping out the whitespace after reading:

```
line = f.readline().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

python has a package called pandas. By using pandas we can read CSV file in dataframe format.

`import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("datset_small.csv")`

Please post your content in CSV file so that I can help you out

Comment: Seems like overkill to install the third party library pandas in order to read csv files, when there's already a `csv` module preinstalled with Python. I do like the general idea of using a csv parser instead of extracting the data manually, however.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved using dataframe.
example code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd

malware_list = ["FakeInstaller","DroidKungFu", "Plankton",
            "Opfake", "GingerMaster", "BaseBridge",
            "Iconosys", "Kmin", "FakeDoc", "Geinimi",
            "Adrd", "DroidDream", "LinuxLotoor", "GoldDream"
            "MobileTx", "FakeRun", "SendPay", "Gappusin",
            "Imlog", "SMSreg"]
# read csv into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('datset_small.csv')
print(df['FAMILY'].isin(malware_list))
```

output is

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
```

sample csv used is

```
NAME,FAMILY
090b5be26bcc4df6186124c2b47831eb96761fcf61282d63e13fa235a20c7539,Plankton
bedf51a5732d94c173bcd8ed918333954f5a78307c2a2f064b97b43278330f54,DroidKungFu
149bde78b32be3c4c25379dd6c3310ce08eaf58804067a9870cfe7b4f51e62fe,Plankton
```

Answer (score 0):

I would you set instead of list for speed and definitely Pandas is better due to speed and easiness of the code. You can use x in y logic to get the results ;)

```
import io #not needed in your case
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''090b5be26bcc4df6186124c2b47831eb96761fcf61282d63e13fa235a20c7539,Plankton 
bedf51a5732d94c173bcd8ed918333954f5a78307c2a2f064b97b43278330f54,DroidKungFu 
149bde78b32be3c4c25379dd6c3310ce08eaf58804067a9870cfe7b4f51e62fe,Plankton''')

df = pd.read_csv(data,sep=',',header=None)
malware_set = ("FakeInstaller","DroidKungFu", "Plankton",
            "Opfake", "GingerMaster", "BaseBridge",
            "Iconosys", "Kmin", "FakeDoc", "Geinimi",
            "Adrd", "DroidDream", "LinuxLotoor", "GoldDream"
            "MobileTx", "FakeRun", "SendPay", "Gappusin",
            "Imlog", "SMSreg")



df.columns = ['id','software']

df['malware'] = df['software'].apply(lambda x: x.strip() in malware_set)

print(df)
```